# c++ return file connection to a member, so can be used by other methods of the same class

Tags: c++, file, oop, file-io, singleton

I am coming from PHP. In PHP we can return the file handler to a variable:

```
    class FileHandler
    {
      private $_fileHandler;

      public function __construct()
       {
              $this->_fileHandler = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
       }

      public function writeToFile($sentence)
       {
               fwrite($this->_fileHandler, $sentence);
       }
     }
```

The issue I am facing is that in c++ it gives error when I want it to assign to  a member so I can use it through my class

```
  FileUtils::FileUtils()
  {
    // I do not what type of variable to create to assign it
    string handler = std::ofstream out("readme.txt",std::ios::app); //throws error. 
    // I need it to be returned to member so I do not have to open the file in every other method
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a filestream object, that you can pass by reference:

```
void handle_file(std::fstream &filestream, const std::string& filename) {
    filestream.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in);//you can change the mode depending on what you want to do
    //do other things to the file - i.e. input/output
    //...
}
```

USAGE (in int main or similar):

```
std::fstream filestream;
std::string filename;

handle_file(filestream, filename);
```

This way, you can pass the original `filestream` object to do whatever you please with the file. Also note that if you wanted to use only input filestreams you could specialize your function to `std::ifstream`, and conversely to output filestreams with `std::ofstream`.

REFERENCES:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream